# Android Fingerprint Login - Possible or not

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fingerprint-api

I am developing one app in which user will be able to login with fingerprint. As far as I know the storage of fingerprint is local O.S dependent. If I want to achieve this through server end how can I make it work ?

> Ex. If a user enter a user name, He or she will be asked to enter
>   password or use his finger print for login. Based on username and
>   fingerprint his/her desired role will be recognized.

Please add your valuable replies.

Answer (score 5):

You're correct that the fingerprint data is completely handled by the OS. In fact, your app won't even be able to distinguish between the different enrolled fingerprints.

All you can do is help a faster login using the device enrolled fingerprints (although be aware that any enrolled fingerprint can be used for authenticating the user).

May be this Android Developer's [blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html) can help with further details.